# Module h2o not found in anaconda python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, h2o

I have installed h2o package on anaconda python, however, I get the following error on jupyter notebook:

```python
import h2o
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-accdebc0c7de> in <module>
----> 1 import h2o

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2o'
```

From the conda list I can see that the installed h2o version is the following:

```
conda list h2o
```

```
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
h2o                       3.18.0.2                      0    anaconda
```

> (Is it normal that the build version is 0 here?)

The python version is 3.7.4.

I also tried the following

```
conda install -c h2oai h2o
```

and I get

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

Any ideas why the h2o package isn't working?
Thanks for your time!

> AMC, regarding the anaconda environments, after running:
>
> ```
> conda info --envs
> ```
>
> I get:
>
> ```
> # conda environments:
> #
> base                  *  C:\Users\ncham***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
> ```
>
> As far as I can see, there is only one environment...

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? The problem usually is that you added the package to a particular Python installation and are running the program with a different one.

Comment: I get:
`base    C:\Users\ncham***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`
I think is the only environment I have . . .

Comment: Did you really install the Python version via "conda install h2o-py"? "conda install h2o" only installs the java package as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577923/python-cannot-find-package-h2o-in-anaconda

Comment: I think I installed it with `conda install -c h2oai h2o`.
The `conda install h2o-py` fails.. i.e.:
`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done`
`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`
`Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`
`Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done`
`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`
Maybe we have found something here . . .

Comment: There is a large thread about this issue here (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9367). Can you find the solution somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is the official guide for installing [H2O](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#:%7E:text=in%20Jupyter%20Notebook.-,Install%20on%20Hadoop,you%20need%20to%20get%20started.&text=Point%20your%20browser%20to%20H2O.) on Anaconda.
2. Jump to the **Install on Anaconda Cloud** part, make sure your Python's version is compatible with h2o module (2.7,3.5 and 3.6), follow the steps and you will be able to import h2o module through py36 channel.
   Hope this answer helps you.